# MaTeX shadow option?

Tags: plotting, graphics, text, matex, inset

When I create my graphics, I find that the tex objects created with MaTeX either clash with other objects (such as a coordinate grid) or, if I add a background, erase too much. Is there another option that would create just the right amount of emptiness around the text?

```
Graphics[{
 Table[Line[{{-2, y}, {2, y}}], {y, -2, 2, .1}],
 Table[Line[{{x, -2}, {x, 2}}], {x, -2, 2, .1}],
 Inset[MaTeX["x", Magnification -> 6], {0, 0}],
 Inset[MaTeX["x", Magnification -> 6], {1, 1}, Background -> White]
 }, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MaTeX` returns plain [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html), usually with some [`FilledCurve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledCurve.html) inside. You can disassemble it and try to modify it.

Here I try an idea where we make the strokes very thick to create an outline of the graphics.

```
ClearAll[outline]
outline[thickness_: 6, colour_: White][ma_] :=
 Show[
  Insert[ma, 
   EdgeForm@Directive[CapForm["Round"], JoinForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[thickness], colour], 
   {{1, 1}}
  ],
  ma
 ]
```

```
Graphics[{Table[Line[{{-2, y}, {2, y}}], {y, -2, 2, .1}], 
  Table[Line[{{x, -2}, {x, 2}}], {x, -2, 2, .1}], 
  Inset[outline[]@MaTeX["x^2", Magnification -> 6], {0, 1}],
  Inset[outline[8, GrayLevel[.85]]@MaTeX["x^2", Magnification -> 6], {0, 0}],
  Inset[outline[20, Lighter[Yellow, 2/3]]@MaTeX["x^2", Magnification -> 6], {0, -1}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{Table[Line[{{-2, y}, {2, y}}], {y, -2, 2, .1}], 
  Table[Line[{{x, -2}, {x, 2}}], {x, -2, 2, .1}], 
  Inset[outline[10]@MaTeX["\\int_0^\\infty \!\!\! e^{-\\lambda x}\\; dx", Magnification -> 5], {0, 0}]
  },
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

I do not expect that this will work flawlessly everywhere, but it may be a good start for you. One issue I noticed is that very thick outlines fail around the dots on an `i` or `j`.

---

A similar effect can be achieved with [a number of $\LaTeX$ packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25241/6302). I do not expect all of these to play well with MaTeX, so you will have to experiment. The `contour` package seems to work.

```
MaTeX["\\contour{green}{$x^2+y$}", 
 "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{contour}", "\\contourlength{1pt}", 
   "\\contournumber{20}"}, FontSize -> 24, Magnification -> 3]
```

[image]

You should also experiment with the `pdfrender` package.