# Using MaTeX with outline to create transparency around the equation

Tags: plotting, color, labeling, matex, opacity

Is there a way to combine **outline** around equations as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214500/matex-shadow-option/214504#214504), with the ideas proposed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253763/color-that-imposes-transparency) to create images with transparent background?

Currently, since outline requires a color, I end up with images as in this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: please make your question self contained. Links can be used as reference. But you should not expect people to jump to different places to figure what code to use and read all those questions and answers use and so on.